# WPF Remove DropShadow Effect

Tags: wpf, vb.net, effect, dropshadow

Right now if I click Button A, Button B shows a DropShadow effect:

```
 Private Sub ButtonA_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonA.Click

 Dim objDropShadow As New DropShadowEffect
            objDropShadow.ShadowDepth = 0
            objDropShadow.BlurRadius = 30
            objDropShadow.Color = Colors.GreenYellow

            Me.ButtonB.Effect = objDropShadow

End Sub
```

If I clicked Button C how would I remove the DropShadow effect from Button B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub ButtonC_Click(
  ByVal sender As System.Object, 
  ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButtonC.Click

 Dim objDropShadow As New DropShadowEffect
            objDropShadow.ShadowDepth = 0
            objDropShadow.BlurRadius = 0
            objDropShadow.Color = Colors.Transparent

            Me.ButtonB.Effect = objDropShadow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it

```
Me.ButtonB.Effect = Nothing        // VB.Net
this.ButtonB.Effect = null;        // C#
```